# Two unique values in column Laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a reservation system for a media library, the goal is to book a room for a certain time. There are 8 time slots in total with a start_time & end_time.

The user has to fill in a date and I have to check what time slots are still available at that date.

So, for example.. there can only be one row in the database that contains **date:** 2016-12-08 **time_slot:** 3.

How do I check if this row exists in my database using Eloquent?

Answer (score 2):

You can do laravel model query to check if there is any results, like this :

```
$data = Model::where('date','2016-12-08 ')->where('time_slot', 3)->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Since I'm fairly new to Laravel and working with MVC, can you tell me how to implement this?

Comment: try to search for using `models` in laravel.. it will be super easy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a slot table with the fields you are sharing. Slot table: id, date, time_slot...

```
$your_date = 2016-12-08;
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($your_date));
$time_slot: 3;

$slot = Slot::where('date', $date)->where('slot', $time_slot)->first();

if($slot == null) {
  // book can be made
}
else {
  // already booked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help pf Laravel Query Builder's [`exists`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists) for checking the if the fields are present in database like this:

```
$exists = Model::whereDate('date', '2016-12-08')
                ->where('time_slot', 3)
                ->exists();
```

> Here `exists` returns a boolean value, which depends upon the existence of the query above!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Since I'm fairly new to Laravel and working with MVC, can you tell me how to implement this?

Comment: I think I've mentioned the full implantation in the answer itself!